# Magento 1.7: PCI scan Can't Pass category URL with 'mode' param

Tags: magento-1.7, security, sql, pci, compromise-injection

Don't know why but the PCI scan do not pass Category URL of Magento and provide a SQL injection with 'mode' param in the below format.

```
/main-category/sub-category/l/price:10-20/category-name.html?dir=desc&mode=x'%2Bsleep(15)%2B'&order=name HTTP/1.0
```

How should I resolve this type of issue? 
Do anybody have gone through it, if yes please provide your kind suggestions.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you using nginx or apache?

In nginx, you can do the following, in your `server { }` block;

```
if ($arg_order ~* .+(select|create|insert|update|drop|delete|concat|alter|load|sleep)) {
   return 403;
}
```

For apache in .htaccess;

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark|sleep).* [NC,OR]
```

Comment: Added apache rule, but your Magento module used for filtering may have an SQL vulnerability. Please post what module you're using for that.

Comment: How could I test that the above solution is working ?

Comment: @amit_game try accessing the url that failed in your pci scan, of your original Q.

Comment: I tried It. its providing access to the result , what I want that if a url have a specious function like sleep, it stop navigation or redirect to 404 page